# Hibernate composite key having only foriegn keys

Tags: hibernate

I have an application where there is a manytomany relationship. The part where creation of rows is done is working fine. Now I also need to retreive records and delete only the linkages while maintaining the parents.

For this I have added another class representing the Link. This class contains no additional column but an id that is represented using another class. The id class contains the foreign keys.

My question is that the @many to many annotation will also need to be in the id class or not?

I have tried that and while listing it gives me a 'not an association' exception foe the alias

This is my relevant code:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name="trans.documentlink")
public class DocumentObjectLink
{

     @Id
      private LinkId id;

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public LinkId getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(LinkId id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }


}

    @Embeddable
public class LinkId implements Serializable
{
    //private String comment;
    private DocumentGroup document;
    private DocumentFile docFile;

public LinkId(DocumentFile fileId, DocumentGroup docId)
{
    super();
    this.docFile = fileId;
    this.document = docId;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    LinkId cp =(LinkId)obj;
    if(this.docFile.equals(cp.getDocFile()) && this.document.equals(cp.getDocument())){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return this.docFile.hashCode()+this.document.hashCode();
}

/**
 * @return the documentFile
 */
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "fileid" , nullable = false)
public DocumentFile getDocFile()
{
    return docFile;
}
/**
 * @param documentFile the documentFile to set
 */
public void setDocFile(DocumentFile documentFile)
{
    this.docFile = documentFile;
}


/**
 * @return the document
 */
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "documentid", nullable = false)
public DocumentGroup getDocument()
{
    return document;
}
/**
 * @param document the document to set
 */
public void setDocument(DocumentGroup document)
{
    this.document = document;
}

}
```

The code where I get the exception is:

```
@Override
public boolean deleteOnlyLinks(long documentId, String nodeId)
{
    Criteria docFile = null;
    try
    {
        docFile = getCriteria(DocumentObjectLink.class);
    docFile.createAlias("id.docFile", "file");
    docFile.createAlias("id.document", "doc");
    docFile.add(Restrictions.eq("file.id", documentId));
    docFile.add(Restrictions.eq("doc.nodeId", nodeId));
    List<DocumentObjectLink> lst =  docFile.list();
        if(lst.size() > 0)
        {
            getCrntSession().delete(lst.get(0));
        }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {

        logger.debug("Error while deleting" + documentId);
        throw new DMSException("Error while deleting" + documentId,ErrorCode.DELETE,e);
    }
    return true;

}
```

The exception is:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: not an association: id.docFile
```

EDIT::

I have tried to add a int column called id to the db which isnt a primary key but has a generated value. Then I moved the foriegn keys to the documentobjectlink class and tried to run the following code

```
@Override
public boolean deleteOnlyLinks(long documentId, String nodeId)
{
    Criteria docFile = null;
    try
    {
        docFile = getCriteria(DocumentObjectLink.class);
        docFile.createAlias("docFile", "file");
        docFile.createAlias("document", "doc");
        docFile.add(Restrictions.eq("file.id", documentId));
        docFile.add(Restrictions.eq("doc.nodeId", nodeId));
        List<DocumentObjectLink> lst =  docFile.list();
        if(lst.size() > 0)
        {
            getCrntSession().delete(lst.get(0));
        }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {

        logger.debug("Error while deleting" + documentId);
        throw new DMSException("Error while deleting" + documentId,ErrorCode.DELETE,e);
    }
    return true;

}
```

Now I am getting the exception

```
not an association: docFile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Prems answer I realized that it was difficult to understand my requirement.

I wanted to perform a query with an alias. I did not have the id value to one of the parts of the id. As you can see I had the nodeId which is not the primary key in the DocumentGroup table. Due to this I was trying to put the objects in the ID class rather than the id's.

I have now changed my code to put only id's as a composite key class. I had to add another query to retrieve the row from DocumentGroup table and then use the id from that in the next query.

I only wanted to avoid multiple db visits.

Hope this helps someone with a similar problem

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very verbose to read through. So this example M2M may help.

- One student "can take" a list of classes/courses [Student table with #ID]
- One class/course "has many" students taking it. [Course table with #ID]

Now flatten this M2M with an association table "StudentCourse" that will make two One2One associations.

SudentCourse [composite primary key  (studentID, courseID)], at db level you will also create studentID pointing to Student.ID and courseID pointing to Course.ID - fks.

Hibernate should delete the links appropriately.

Look at Section 7.5.3: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/associations.html

```
create table Person ( personId bigint not null primary key )
create table PersonAddress ( personId bigint not null, addressId bigint not null, primary key (personId, addressId) )
create table Address ( addressId bigint not null primary key )
```

Comment: from this answer i understand that you want me to put ids rather than actual objects in the association table id class. I will try doing this and update the question